# Flux of the amount of buffalo entering a square kilometer per minute

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

[image]

So Eq.(13) is just $\int F.n dS = \int \int div(F) dA$

So I did $div(F) = \nabla . F = y+1$, then I did $\int_2^3 \int_2^3 y + 1 dx dy = \int_2^3 y + 1 dy = .5(3^2) + 3 - (.5(2^2) + 2) = 3.5$ This multiplied by density is 1750.

This is not the answer. The answer is 29.2

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: Rogawski Calculus 3rd edition

Answer (score 1):

The value 1750 corresponds with the number of buffalo entering/leaving the area per hour. Divide by 60 to get 29.2.

Comment: This answer is correct. It is asking for buffalo per minute and the flux is given per hour